# (python 3) How to check if non strings begin with a vowel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Issue: I am trying to check for vowels within a class attribute.

The goal is to use 'a' or 'an' depending on whether the first letter of self.type is a vowel.

I've tried searching, but all the responses are about regular strings.

How do I check if self.type begins with a vowel?

Is there a better way to do this?

```
class robot:
    def __init__(self, name, color, type):
        self.name = name
        self.color =color
        self.type = type

    def robot_intro(self):
        print("My name is", self.name)
        print("I am", self.color)
        if self.type.lower() startswith ("a","e","i","o","u"):
            print("I am an", self.type)
        else:
            print("I am a", self.type)

r1 = robot("C3PO", "gold", "protocol droid")
r2 = robot("R2D2", "white and blue", "astromech droid")
r3 = robot("BB8", "white and orange", "astromech droid")

r1.robot_intro()
r2.robot_intro()
r3.robot_intro()
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not a regular string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` is a string, it doesn't matter it's a class attribute. Treat it like a regular string. Even attributes are variables which have basic types (e.g integer, float, string, list) or a bit more complex type (like another class).

As for your question, the following lines check if first letter is a vowel:

```py
if self.type.lower()[0] in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
    print("I am an", self.type)
else:
    print("I am a", self.type)
```

`self.type.lower()[0]` returns the first letter of `self.type` but in lower-case. Then it searches if it's inside the list `["a","e","i","o","u"]`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
class robot:
    def __init__(self, name, color, type):
        self.name = name
        self.color =color
        self.type = type

    def robot_intro(self):
        print("My name is", self.name)
        print("I am", self.color)
        if str(self.type).lower()[0] in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
            print("I am an", self.type)
        else:
            print("I am a", self.type)

r1 = robot("C3PO", "gold", "protocol droid")
r2 = robot("R2D2", "white and blue", "astromech droid")
r3 = robot("BB8", "white and orange", "astromech droid")

r1.robot_intro()
r2.robot_intro()
r3.robot_intro()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has no char, only strings, but you can cut out the first char as a string self.type[0].lower() and compare it 5 times or find it in a vowel string:

```
if "aeiou".find( self.type[0].lower() ) != -1:
```

Note I am being careful to homogenize the case.